# as3 - How to add a movieclip into the parent's parent?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a gun child inside of a movieclip called "player" and "player" is inside another movieclip called "level one".

So inside the gun class, the code spawns a bullet. Which has to spawn in the parent's parent. So the bullet can shoot into the level.

```
private function fire(m: MouseEvent)
{
    //when bullet fired
    var b = new Bullet;
    MovieClip(MovieClip(parent).parent).addChild(b);
}
```

However, the bullet never appears in the parent's parent. What could be the issue here?

UPDATED CODE:

In gun class:

```
function fire(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event('fire!', true));
}
```

In player class:

```
protected function fire(e: Event)
    {
        var b: Bullet = new Bullet();
        // bullet must be in same position and angle as player.gun
        b.rotation = player.gun.rotation;
        b.x = player.gun.x; + player.gun.width * Math.cos(player.gun.rotation / 180 * Math.PI);
        b.y = player.gun.y + player.gun.width * Math.sin(player.gun.rotation / 180 * Math.PI);
        addChild(b);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you fire a custom event from within your `Gun` object, and capture it wherever the bullet needs to spawn?

Comment: I just tried something very similar, and this seems to work for me. The `Bullet` object gets added to the `LevelOne` object.

Comment: @Crook That should work (at least that visible code). Is your `fire()` function is executed ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed to strong typing the variable and add parentheses
Try 
    var b:Bullet = new Bullet();

Why don't you keep a reference to the parent.parent?

```
var b:Bullet = new Bullet(parent)
...
public function Bullet(spawnTarget:MovieClip)
{
    _spawnTarget = spawnTarget;
}

private function fire(m: MouseEvent)
{
    //when bullet fired
    var b = new Bullet;
    _spawnTarget.addChild(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parent.parent is risky because you'd always need to make sure that the gun class is instantiated in a child of the game class. Also, you can't create guns in any other position in the hierarchy which can be a problem if your game grows bigger.

You can solve this with listeners (as the comments state, and this is an example of passing a game reference. Each instance receives a reference to game, so each instance can call public function on game:

**Game.as**

```
myPlayer = new Player(this);
public function addBulletToWorld(){
}
```

**Player.as**

```
public function Player(game){
    myGun = new Gun(game);
}
```

**Gun.as**

```
public function Gun(game){
    game.addBulletToWorld();
}
```

Comment: That is just such a code smell to not only have child objects knowing about their parents but having some child objects _only_ knowing about the parent so they can pass that information to their own children.

Comment: True, although one can assume that the Player needs to know about Game as well. I chose the simplest solution I can think of here, without introducing new concepts to beginning programmers.

Comment: I would not like to write this in every level as I have multiple levels. So I would prefer using parent.parent. Is there a solution for parent.parent?

Comment: Well you could try parent.parent.spawnBullet();, and then in the main class you place the function spawnBullet() { addChild(new Bullet());

Comment: I think the event listener is the best way to avoid having to write that in every level. @Kokodoko, I don't think it does beginners any favors to let them get into habits that will leave them with spaghetti code and limited career prospects, even in Flash.

Comment: Note that [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-events-basix--active-10018) is marked as a beginner tutorial.

Comment: That is a great tutorial and a perfect solution for this problem. Just for the sake of argument: passing references around would not immediately limit your careers prospects imho :) It's often done (for example in engines like Unity and Monogame) when referencing a main game class that will always exist.

Comment: I guess it depends if you want to get an architect position with a really top-notch company. I guess people wanting to do that are probably not primarily developing in Flash today. The problem is that if you develop such habits as a new developer, they are really hard to shake. IMO  a lot of frameworks encourage poor habits, unfortunately. A good architect will know how to build walls that hide that junk from the rest of their code.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely insist on using the parent.parent thing, just set a break point at that line and see what parent.parent actually is, then adjust as needed to match your actual structure. But aside from the fact that this is just bad practice, it's going to limit you to where you can't use this Class anywhere but at that one depth.

I'd recommend just generating a custom event when you want to fire the bullet, and letting the grandparent handle it.

In Gun:

```
function fire(e:MoudeEvent):void {
    dispatchEvent(new Event('fire!', true));//setting it true lets it bubble up to the parent
}
```

In Game

```
protected var bullets:Vector. = new Vector();
public function Game() {
    addEventListener('fire!', fire);
}
//note I worked with Flex too long to use private methods very often
protected function fire(e:Event) {
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
    bullet.x = MoveClip(e.target).x);
    bullet.y = MoveClip(e.target).y);
    addChild(bullet);
    bullets.push(bullet);//I assume you're going to want to move this or something, so we need to store it to manage it
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the bullet still does not show in the game. I updated my code to show you what I did.

Comment: It seems like the bullet is added but it cannot be added to the area where the gun is. I tried b.x = player.gun.x(...) but it seems like the game class cannot spawn the bullet to the gun's position because it's inside of another movieclip? Is there a solution to this?

Comment: One way to handle this is to have the Player listen for mouse events on gun and then dispatch the "fire!" event when it hears them. Then the x and y will be relative to the player. I can think of two or three other ways to resolve the problem, but try that one first. I don't want to confuse you.